# How to place a condition in a different method that compares elements that will decide to do a task or not?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement, methods

I have an array that consists of numbers that are in an order that is not decided by me. For example: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

I have written this code in different methods, and I want to add code that would now take pos1 and pos2 and compare them, and only switch position if the statement that pos2 is less than pos1. comparing it through from pos1 to pos2; pos2 to pos3; pos3 to pos4; etc.

Code:

```
static void nameSwitch(  int[] array, int pos1, int pos2 ) {

    int temp = array[pos1];
    array[pos1] = array[pos2];
    array[pos2] = temp;


}

static void firstNameToLast() {

     int [] values = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < values.length; i+=2) {
            swap(values, i, i+1);
        }
        System.out.println( + Arrays.toString(values));
     }



static void goingThrough( int[] nums) {
    //comparing pos1 and pos2, etc  area of confusion
    System.out.println(  + Arrays.toString( nums ) );   
 }
```

after going through the last loop, I want the output to be, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,,9,10 to stay the same, but if i had numbers such as, 2,4,1,6,8,1,3. i want pos1 to be compared to pos2, and if pos2 is less than pos1, then switch there position.

Comment: You could use a for-loop and iterate through your array and then compare each value

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What is the input and what should the output be?

Comment: You should do exactly as you describe. Does `if (values[pos2] < values[pos1]) { ... swap ... }` not work out for you? By the way your snippet is confusing, you have `nameSwitch` which you do not use, and `swap` which you do not define.

Comment: The code will not work because the `swap` method never changes the actual array itself. @OP, I gave an edit to my answer with more explanation.

Comment: Oh, I understand that, but if i had different integers such as the ones i suggested in my orginal problem, they would, right?

Comment: As it is now, no. Unless `values` is a class level variable, and your `swap` method is in the same class, then maybe it would work. But if it's not, then you're swap method is performing actions that are changing the array in the parameters but not the array that you're working with, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not too difficult. Start by writing a loop that circles the array, checks the current object and the one next to it, and swaps them if the first position is larger, like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length - 1; i++){
   if(myArray[i] > myArray[i + 1]{
      myArray = swapElements(myArray, i, i + 1);
   }
}
```

And then your swap elements might look like this:

```
private int[] swapElements(int[] arr, int first, int second){
   int temp = arr[first];
   arr[first] = arr[second];
   arr[second] = temp;
   return arr;
}
```

Now, if you want to sort the entire array, there are easier ways to do it. If you are simply doing just this, swapping elements, I would try the above.

**EDIT**

I think the reason your code will not work is because while you call the `swap` method, it does not change the value of the array itself, it only changes it within the method. Notice how in my solution, I set the array equal to what is returned from the method. Am I correct in assuming that the output you were actually receiving was the original array itself?

Comment: Also notice that my for loop goes until `myArray.length - 1`. This ensures you stop at the second to last element, and thus avoiding an index out of bounds exception.

Comment: No one chek that @McAdam331 xD =)

Comment: `myArray.length - 1` no one care of this

Comment: @AndreaBori well they should unless they want an exception to be thrown when they execute the code.

Comment: i know sometimes the problem is the coder not the code =P

Comment: @AndreaBori I'm still lost, are you trying to imply there's a problem with my code?

Comment: nonono!! only say that i see many many times that error =) nothing else!

Answer (score 1):

To sort your arrays, you the following code in your swap method

```
for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
            if (array[i] < array[j]) {
                int temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps